# How to prevent bootstrap from making font bold?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Without including the bootstrap link in this simple example, the following code performs as expected:  Hovering over any word turns the word red, and hovering away returns it to black.

With the bootstrap link included, the change from red/black still works fine, but for some reason, the font becomes bold and stays that way.

Is there a way to prevent bootstrap from leaving the font bold when hovering away?

Demonstrates bold turning on after hovering away:  http://jsfiddle.net/vLtsw4vb/

Commenting out or removing the bootstrap link results in the desired behavior.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready (function () {
            $('.ztag')
            .hover (
                function () {
                    $(this).css({color: '#ff0000'})

                },
                function () {
                    $(this).css({color: '#000000'})
                }
            )
        }) 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span class='ztag'>foo</span>
    <span class='ztag'>bar</span>
    <span class='ztag'>stuff</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's the :focus style you need to reset/cascade

Comment: Can you give me an example of that?

Comment: @dandavis did you mean this?  <style>
    .ztag:focus {font-weight: normal}
</style>  If so, that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original black color which bootstrap was using was `#333`. You change it to `#000` which makes it appear bolder.

Try this

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $('.ztag')
    .hover (
        function () {
            $(this).css({color: '#ff0000'})
        },
        function () {
            $(this).css({color: '#333333'})
        }
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `font-weight` value, see: http://jsfiddle.net/vLtsw4vb/2/